# My Bleu score is different from nltk bleu score

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, nlp, machine-translation

I tried to calculate the bleu score from scratch.

```
import numpy as np
reference = 'hello how are you i am good here'
output = 'hello baby are you i am fine here'

# calculate Brevity penalty
BP = 0
if len(reference) < len(output):
    BP = 1
else:
    BP = np.exp(1-(len(reference)/len(output)))

def Bleu(ref, pred):
    count = []
    clip_count = []

    for i in range(1, len(pred)):
        clp = 0
        cp = 0
        start = set()
        for j in range(len(pred)):
            if j+i >len(pred):
                continue

            goal = pred[j:i+j]

            sum = ''
            for k in goal:
                sum += k+' '

            final = sum[:-1]

            cp += 1
            if final in ref:
                if final in start:
                    continue
                else:
                    clp += 1
                    start.add(final)


        clip_count.append(clp)
        count.append(cp)

    return clip_count, count

clip, count = Bleu(reference, output.split())

pn = sum(np.divide(clip, count))

bleu = np.exp((1/len(clip)) * pn) * BP

print(bleu)
```

The output from nltk python Bleu score

```
import nltk

t = 'hello how are you i am good here'
m = 'hello baby are you i am fine here'
hypothesis = m.split()
reference = t.split()
#there may be several references
BLEUscore = nltk.translate.bleu_score.sentence_bleu([reference], hypothesis)
print(BLEUscore)
```

My question is:

Q1. The both bleu scores are not matching, what is the mistake?? somebody please help me out

Q2. If we try to calculate Bleu score, the value of bleu score will be always greater then 1 because the formula for bleu score is

Bleu score-> exp( 1/n * sum(precision n-gram) ) * Brevity_Penalty

The exponential function (e^x) is always greater then 1 if x is +ve, and the value of precision n-gram is always positive.

Then why general documents say that bleu score value should be in between 0 to 1???

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in the formula. Exponentiating the average *n*-gram precisions would not have any reasonable interpretation. It should be a [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean). The geometric mean of numbers between 0 and 1 will be always between 0 and 1. The way it is usually computed is exponentiating the average of the log precisions because otherwise, you would multiply small numbers which could lead to errors from float underflow.

Here is the formula from the [original paper](https://aclanthology.org/P02-1040.pdf):

[image]

Comment: If you think the answer is correct, please mark it so, so other people with a similar problem know.

Comment: I would have, but it says "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.".